# What is the best steps to snap the torus to floor level?

Tags: snapping

I create a basic torus and at default setting the torus will not lay on ground level (z=0). So i tried couple way to snap it to the floor and couldn't get the efficient way to do it. Can someone show me the best and fast way using snap to level the torus so the bottom part will lay perfectly on floor. Don't use fix number ,  so it can also applicable to any other random size of torus.

Thanks

Comment: [Related 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects/42110) and [Related 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95728/set-object-origin-to-minimum-z-set-to-floor-using-examples-from-tlousky)

Answer (score 1):

Align Objects [space menu search]

The Torus was selected. Next yellow floor last to become the active object.

[image]

- The figure on the right shows two objects not yet aligned.  Torus and Plane.
- The figure on the  left show two objects aligned.
- The Tool Shelf shows the parameters used in this example ... Negative Sides, Active, Align Z.  The plane has the negative side and positive side in the same location .... plane.

Other options show in the Tool Shelf. Selection, 3D Cursor, Scene Origin

[image]